# как отправить текст и файл (изображение) через discord py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Здраствуйте, мне надо через библиотеку discord в python выводить в чат картинку прикреплённую к тексту, чтобы выглядело примерно так:[image: вот пример]

как это сделать через `await ctx.send`?
либо же другие варианты

P.s. проше говоря, надо объединить эти две строчки:

```
await ctx.send( f'`текст`' )
await ctx.send(file=discord.File("profile.jpg"))
```

Comment: разобрался сам))
используйте: await ctx.send('Тест', file=discord.File('test.png'))

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ на вопрос - создайте ответ от себя и поясните решение проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await ctx.send('твой текст', file=discord.File(file))
```

или так

```
await ctx.send(content ='твой текст', file=discord.File(file))
```